# Testing infinite api requests on a web app

Tags: selenium, puppeteer, cypress

I run into an error where a section of the web app we are testing runs in an infinite XHR requests loop.

I'm trying to find the best way to check each section of the web app for verifying the requests are not high.

The initial idea is to use selenium with mobproxy but is really slow, the other solution looks like a to use puppeteer or cypress for just try to catch these requests.

How you test this kind of overload XHR request